# Alternative to Crashlytics `+ (CLSStackFrame *)stackFrameWithAddress:(NSUInteger)address`

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, watchdog

Fabric Crashlytics exposed a function to create stack trace frames from memory address:

```
[CLSStackFrame stackFrameWithAddress:address]
```

The alternative class in Firebase Crashlytics is `FIRStackFrame` which lacks this method and exposes a single initializtion method:

```
FIRStackFrame stackFrameWithSymbol:file:line:
```

Any ideas about how to convert address to `FIRStackFrame`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was released in Firebase Crashlytics today. See the release notes [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#crashlytics).

You can use the API as follows:

```
[FIRStackTrace stackTraceWithSymbol:symbol file:file line:line];
```